# Как найти все картинки png для темы tkinter на tcl?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

Встретился с проблемой что tcl не может найти файлы в директории. Как настроить так, чтобы он искал файлы в одной папке с самим tcl файлом?(надо найти все файлы png) Вот код, который был изначально указан:

```
proc LoadImages {imgdir} {
    variable I
    foreach file [glob -directory  *.png] {
        set img [file tail [file rootname $file]]
        set I($img) [image create photo -file $file -format png]
    }
}
LoadImages [file join [file dirname [info script]] breeze]
```

Проблема в том, что задан поиск png файлов в папке breeze, которая находится вместе с tcl файлом. Но он почему-то не видит файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы запускаете скрипт из той же директории, в которой он находится,
то всё проcто:

```tcl
foreach file [glob *.png] {
    puts $file
}
```

Если же скрипт запускается из другого места, то придётся повозиться:

```tcl
set scriptDir [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]
set globString [file join $scriptDir *.png]
foreach file [glob $globString] {
    puts $file
}
```

Comment: Все равно python пишет : _tkinter.TclError: no files matched glob pattern "*.png"

Comment: Есть еще какие-нибудь предложения?

Comment: Вот ссылка на саму тему: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fGkoTyJKRonMy2wHYxpN5yeiM_BeWPtm/view?usp=drivesdk